Nice way to load data in-time with Svelte
In Svelte, we have a very nice and beautiful way to load some data in time and render it using @const:
<script>
    let a = false;
</script>
    
<button on:click={() => a = !a}></button>
{#if a}
    {@const table = axios.get(...)}
    {#await table}
        <Spinner />
    {:then table}
        ...
    {/await} 
{/if}

This way, we don't really have to declare anything in the body. But sometimes we might need to have some logic inside:
<script>
    let a = false;
</script>
    
<button on:click={() => a = !a}></button>
{#if a}
   {@const table = axios.get(...)}
   {#await table}
       <Spinner />
   {:then table}
       {#each table as x}
           <button on:click={() => x.open = true}>
               Open row!
           </button>
           {#if x.open === true}
               ...
           {/if}
       {/each}
   {/await} 
{/if}

And it will not work, since table is a @const. I want to find a clever and simple way to work this out. Is there any good practice I can use here instead of @const to not overload body of component with state variables?

The key thing here is ability to send requests only when needed (when it's rendered), and my problem was that it can't have it's own state. I tried to imagine some quirky or stateless solution to this (instead of x.open), but didn't came up with anything working. It was something like this:
<script>
    let a = false;
</script>

<button on:click={() => a = !a}></button>
{#if a}
   {@const table = axios.get(...)}
   {#await table}
       <Spinner />
   {:then table}
       {#each table as x}
           {@const open = new class { state = false; toggle = function () { return this.state = !this.state}}}
           <button on:click={() => open.toggle()}>
               Open row!
           </button>
           {#if open.state}
               ...
           {/if}
       {/each}
   {/await} 
{/if} 

Which is, of course, don't work, and even if it did - it's too far from anything holy.
Nonetheless. I kinda got it. If any entity should have state (like open state), then it should have it's own component. It's not ideal for simple structures, but it's the only logical solution I came up with.
